# Gridview Edit external update button.

Tags: asp.net, gridview, textbox, databound, templatefield

I have a gridview in my asp.net page that has one template field for editing a yearly budget. The code follows:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="f_year" HeaderText="Year" ReadOnly="True" `enter code here`>
    <ItemStyle Width="35px" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="o_orgcode" HeaderText="Cost Center " ReadOnly="True" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="o_orgdesc" HeaderText="CostCenterDesc " ReadOnly="True" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="s_subobject" HeaderText="Account " ReadOnly="True" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="s_subdescrip" HeaderText="AccountDesc" ReadOnly="True" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Initial Appropriation">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="$"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditItemApprAmt" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("b_budgetamt", "{0:f}") %>' CssClass="boxright"></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEditItemApprAmt2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("b_budgetamt", "{0:f}") %>' CssClass="boxright"></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="b_initials" ReadOnly="True" >
<ItemStyle Width="35px" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

When my page loads the one template I field I have will automatically appear as a databound text box. I do this because there are multiple money figures to enter at one time and I believe this to be a better function for me site. I want to be able to click an external (meaning external to the gridview) button to loop through the gridview and change those values in my database. Anyone know how to do this, I have not been able to find on the internet an example of this?? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way,

```
foreach(GridVieRrow row in gv.rows)
{
    TextBox txtEditItemApprAmt = row.FindControl("txtEditItemApprAmt");
    string ApprAmt = txtEditItemApprAmt.Text; 
    txtEditItemApprAmt.Text = someTextFunctionOrVariable;
}
```